# Folder seen as file when connected as MTP

Tags: mtp

I have Redmi 1S phone running Andriod 4.3 (MIUI v56).  When connected to a PC (Windows 7 32Bit) in MTP mode, one of the folders named `Backup` (present in internal memory) is seen as a file and effectively inaccessible.

When connected through FTP, that folder is seen and accessible through an FTP client (can be downloaded as well to PC). Folder is accessible from within the File Manager app on phone as well.

I am clueless what is selectively causing this single folder being seen as a file when the device is connected in MTP mode! Any support to solve this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the different way files and folders are handled on Windows when compared to other operating systems, it could be that the folder is corrupted and Windows is seeing it as a file (which it really is in the Android filesystem).  It may be possible to fix this problem by:

1. Creating a new folder,
2. Moving the contents of `Backup` into the new folder,
3. Removing `Backup`, and finally
4. Renaming the new folder to `Backup`

However, depending on what the underlying problem truly is, this may not fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Preston159. As a workaround I could access (it as a folder) and download the contents thru FTP. However when as MTP this particular folder is seen as a file of 4KB size. This folder is created by OS and it stores the backup as bunch of files therein.  I will follow the steps you suggested and check if it helps and update you.

Comment: *'it could be that the folder is corrupted and Windows is seeing it as a file'* -- would you please back this claim with a credible source? I would like to know the reason, or at least folks with similar problem.

Comment: The trick move-copy-rename as suggested by Preston159 worked indeed!  Now the folder is accessible in windows explorer and data remained  intact. This could have been indexing issue as suggested by ballzak. At the moment I don't have ADT so could not run the adb shell command as such.    Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely cause by the path being incorrectly indexed as a file in the MediaStore. Only files scanned and added to the MediaStore shows up in Windows when the device is mounted in MTP mode. Try rescanning the path, to update the MediaStore with the correct path information.

If you have the ADT installed, use ADB:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard/Backup
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still relevant in 2021 since I just encoutered the problem.

Simple solution: rebuild media cache.
Go to Applications, tap the three points in the upper right corner. Choose show processes. Find Media Storage. Clear cache and data. Reboot.
So it seems Windows is the culprit?